# Getting/Applying capitlization mask before/after encoding?

Tags: java, string, encoding, compression, character

My project takes a String `s` and passes an all lower case version `s.toLowerCase()` to a lossless encoder. 
I can convert encode/decode the lower case string just fine, but this obviously would not be practical, so I need to be able to preserve the original String's capitalization somehow.

I was thinking of using `Character.isUpperCase()` to get an array of integers `UpperCaseLetters[]` that represents the locations of all capital letters in `s`. I would then use this array to place a `^` at all locations `UpperCaseLettes[i] + 1` in the encoded string. When decoding the string, I would know that every character preceding a `^` is capital. (By the way, for this encoder will never generate `^` when encoding).

This method seems sloppy to me though. I was also thinking of using bit strings to represent capitalization, but the over all goal of the application is compression, so that would not be very efficient.

Is there any easier way to get and apply capitlization masks for strings? If there is, how much "storage" would it need?

Comment: Why not remove the `toLowerCase` and pass the original string to your encoder?

Comment: I would, but it's a dictionary based encoder and the dictionary only has lower case entries to minimize dictionary size.

Comment: How about using a standard compression algorithm instead?

Comment: I wish that was an option, but this type of encoder is required for the research that I am a part of.

Comment: If you must use your own encoder couldn't you store an array of integer locations (where the uppercases are) and then use that after decoding to set the characters to uppercase again? 
This implies that you can pass that array as well to the receiver - or at least share the information somehow. Hard to tell from your description how the encode/decoder clients are interacting.

Comment: Be careful, not all case mappings are reversible. http://www.unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options:

**Auto-capitalize:**

Use a general algorithm for capitalization, use one of the below techniques to only record the letters that differ between the generated and the actual capitalization. To regenerate, just run the algorithm again and flip the capitalization of all the recorded letters. Assuming there are capital letters where there should be (e.g. start of sentences), this will slow the algorithm down slightly (only by a small constant factor of n, and decent compression is generally much slower than that) and always reduce the amount of storage space required by a few.

**Bitmap of capital positions**:

You've already covered this one, not particularly efficient.

**Prefix capitals with identifying character:**

Also already covered, except that you described postfix, but prefix is generally better and, for a more generic solution, you can also escape the `^` with `^^`. Not a bad idea. Depending on the compression, it might be a good idea to instead use a letter that already appears in the dataset. Either the most or least common letter, or you may have to look at the compression algorithm and do quite a bit of processing to determine the ideal letter to use.

**Store distance of capital from start in any format:**

Has no advantage over distance to next capital (below).

**Distance to next capital - non-bitstring representation:**

Generally less efficient than using bitstrings.

**Bit string = distance to next capital:**

You have a sequence of lengths, each indicating, in sequence, the distances between capitals. So if we have distances `0,3,1,0,5` capitalization would be as follows: `AbcdEfGHijklmNo` (skip 0 characters to the first, 3 character to the second, 1 character to the 3rd, etc.). There are some options available to store this:

- *Fixed length:* Not a good idea since it needs to be = the longest possible distance. An obvious alternative is having some sort of overflow into the next length, but this still uses too much space.
- *Fixed length, different settings:* Best explained with an example - the first 4 bits indicate the length, `00` means there are 2-bits following to indicate the distance, `01` means 4-bits, `10` means 8-bits, `11` means 16-bits, if there's a chance of more than 16-bits, you may want to do something like - `110` means 16-bits, `1110` means 32-bits, `11110` means 64-bits, etc. (this may sound similar to determining the class of a IPv4 address). So `0001010100` would split into `00`-`01`, `01`-`0100`, thus distances 1, 4. Note that the lengths don't have to increment in powers of 2. 16-bits = 65535 characters is a lot and 2-bits = 3 is very little, you can probably make it 4, 6, 8, (16?), (32?), ??? (unless there are a few capitals in a row, then you probably want 2-bits as well).
- *Variable length using escape sequence:* Say the escape sequence is `00`, we want to use all strings that doesn't contain `00`, so the bit value table will look as follows:

  ```
  Bits Value
  1    1
  10   2
  11   3
  101  4 // skipped 100
  110  5
  111  6
  1010 7 // skipped 1000 and 1001
  ```

  `10100101010010101000101000010` will split into `101`, `10101`, `101010`, `101`, 0, `10`. Note that `...1001..` just causes a split ending at the left 1 and a split starting at the right 1, and `...10001...` causes a split ending at the first 0 and a split starting at the right 1, and `...100001...` indicates a 0-valued distance in between. The pseudo-code is something like:

  ```
  if (current value == 1 && zeroCount < 2)
    add to current split
    zeroCount = 0
  else if (current value == 1) // after 00...
    if (zeroCount % 2 == 1) { add zero to current split; zeroCount--; }
    record current split, clear current split
    while (zeroCount > 2) { record 0-distance split; zeroCount -= 2; }
  else zeroCount++
  ```

  This looks like a good solution for short distances, but once the distances become large I suspect you start skipping too many values and the length increases to quickly.

There is no ideal solution, it greatly depends on the data, you'll have to play around with prefixing capitals and different options for bit string distances to see which is best for your typical dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed explanation! This must have taken a while to write, and I appreciate it!